# How can I run laptops that are VMs running on a server?

Tags: laptop, remote-desktop, virtualization

I want laptops where what the user interacts with is a VM running on our server so we can easily switch between and revert them and the laptop itself is safe from being reconfigured/malware infected.

Like remote desktop/VNC except I want the laptop to boot into the desktop that's running on the server as opposed to having its own operating system.

I don't know what hardware and software to use for this or the terminology to search for it. How can I achieve the above please?

This is only for 30 laptops where each laptop has its own user working on their own instance of the same VM at the same time.

Comment: So you want to implement a [thin client](https://www.google.com/#q=thin%20client) basically.  Do you have the required software licenses in order to accomplish that?

Comment: Not yet, I've searched for thin client and zero client but it's not clear what hardware and software to use.

Comment: What software and hardware you use is entirely up to you.  There are many ways to skin this cat.  You have to make that decision, then perhaps ask a specific question, about specific problems you have implementing that decision. Doing this with a laptop would be tougher then implementing it with an actual thin client or zero client but it can be done.  [Here](http://serverfault.com/questions/143077/how-do-i-boot-a-virtual-machine-image-from-my-network) is how you would start to implement it on a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Virtual Desktop Infrastructure (VDI). Virtual desktop infrastructure (VDI) is the practice of hosting a desktop operating system within a virtual machine (VM) running on a centralized server. VDI is a variation on the client/server computing model, sometimes referred to as server-based computing.

[Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/virtual-desktop-infrastructure/overview.aspx) and [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/products/horizon-view) both have VDI solutions.

You can cobble your own solution together, but it will lack most of the very useful functionality of the paid solutions.